# What can cause dlopen: no suitable image found (can't map)?

Tags: macos, dlopen

What can cause the following error when loading an additional bundle using dlopen:

```
dlopen($(OBJ_DIR)/Test-20091217211256.ob, 6): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    $(OBJ_DIR)/Test-20091217211256.ob: can't map
```

Before this error, the process allocates large amounts of memory.

(Substituted `$(OBJ_DIR)` in the error for the actual path to make it more legible).

Answer (score 9):

One possibility is that the shared library you're trying to open isn't actually a shared library.  Run the [`file(1)`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/file.1.html) program on your library to make sure it's actually a shared library.  It should report something like `Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64` on a 64-bit system or `Mach-O dynamically linked shared library i386` on a 32-bit system.

Answer (score 1):

1. 32 bit shared object on 64-bit operating system?
2. missing dependencies?

Answer (score -2):

the solution is just running `npm rebuild node-sass`

credit from: https://github.com/dlmanning/gulp-sass/issues/454